# add routerLink attribute in angular with JavaScript but it not go in link

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I added the `routerLink` Attribute in angular HTML with JavaScript:

```
    let Link: string = "routerLink";
    tailDiv.setAttributeNS(null, Link, this.subItems[i].route)
```

The `tailDiv` element looks like this:

`<div class="tail" routerLink="/panel/country/add">کاربر جدید</div>`

But it does not work and does not go in the link.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add property binding [].

Try like this:

```
let Link: string = "[routerLink]";
```

Then it should look like this:

```
<div class="tail" [routerLink]="/panel/country/add">کاربر جدید</div>
```

Hope it works

Comment: no . it show me this error : `DashboardComponent.html:26 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttributeNS' on 'Element': The qualified name provided ('[routerLink]') contains the invalid name-start character '['.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it in the following way:

component:
`let link = "/panel/country/add";`

template:
`<div class="tail" [routerLink]="link">کاربر جدید</div>`

Comment: You can change the property `link` however you want in the component